# Current development support for CUDA for PCL

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am currently looking at using the CUDA supported codebase within PCL 1.9.1 , in an attempt to improve the performance of a 3D SLAM algorithm which I am testing, via CUDA.

I am facing issues compiling and noticed that the header files for the pcl_cuda namespace was not installed via "make install". Further search brought me to this issue opened two years back where the development of the  CUDA implementations have been dropped   (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2021)

Are anyone aware on the current status on the CUDA support for PCL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CUDA support in PCL was and is highly experimental and is currently under maintenance mode only i.e., no new features are expected to be added in the near future. As mentioned in the issue you linked, the original developers are no longer active in the project.

That being said, you can still compile and install both cuda and gpu modules. So the fact that they are not being installed is a whole different topic. Did you enable

```
cmake .. -DBUILD_CUDA=ON
```

when invoking cmake the first time? These modules are not enabled by default, so you need to compile pcl from source to enable them.